# Why is the code not working properly? CS50 problem half

Tags: c, cs50

I am doing a CS50 problem-[Half](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/problems/1/half/).
I did the problem and it kinda worked, but when entering for example:

```
Bill before tax and tip: 12.50
Sale Tax Percent: 8.875
Tip percent: 20
```

It outputs `$7.80` and not `$8.17`.

When entering:

```
Bill before tax and tip: 100
Sale Tax Percent: 20
Tip percent: 10
```

It works.

Why is that when giving decimals its wrong and when giving round numbers it works?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float half(float bill, float tax, int tip);

int main(void)
{
    float bill_amount = get_float("Bill before tax and tip: ");
    float tax_percent = get_float("Sale Tax Percent: ");
    int tip_percent = get_int("Tip percent: ");

    printf("You will owe $%.2f each!\n", half(bill_amount, tax_percent, tip_percent));
}

// TODO: Complete the function
float half(float bill, float tax, int tip)
{
    float price;
    tax = bill * tax / 100.0;
    tip = (bill + tax) * tip / 100;
    price = bill + tax + tip;
    return price / 2;
}
```

Comment: `tip`, being an `int`, is getting truncated in your floating point calculations.

Comment: How can an `int` get _truncated_?

Comment: @Armali My bad, the floating point result is truncated when stored back into `tip`.

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to overwrite the input parameters to a function, as you are doing to the `tax` and `tip` parameters in the `half()` function. Instead, declare local working variables: `float tax_amount;` and `float tip_amount;` and calculate/use those.

Comment: @Savana01, 1) Save time, enable all warnings. 2) Avoid mixing `float` and `double` math.  Use one. 3) Consider whole number of cents, rather than money as dollars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the input

```
Bill before tax and tip: 12.50
Sale Tax Percent: 8.875
Tip percent: 20
```

the line

```
tax = bill * tax / 100.0;
```

will evaluate to

```
tax = 12.50 * 8.875 / 100.0;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
tax = 1.109375;
```

The line

```
tip = (bill + tax) * tip / 100;
```

is therefore equivalent to

```
tip = (12.50 + 1.109375) * 20 / 100;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
tip = 2.721875;
```

However, the problem is that the variable `tip` is of type `int`, which is only able to represent whole numbers. Therefore, you will be assigning the value `2` instead of `2.721875` to `tip`.

To fix this, I suggest that you create a new variable that is of type `float` and use that variable for storing the value.